# Unable to create directory After Renaming the Project

Tags: swift, xcode

I renamed my project recently. I got this error. I tried to solve this but couldnt figure out whats the reason behind this. i can say that this is about path. but stuck up here.. anybody help me to solve this problem?

```
Unable to create directory: /edX.app/PlugIns/edXTests.xctest (Permission denied)
```

Here is the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information please? Upload a screenshot so we can see exactly where it's showing that

Comment: Did you try to clear build?

Comment: @Rajesh yes i did

Comment: @carlos21 added the screenshot

Comment: @GaneshKumar - did you ever find a fix for this? I'm experiencing the same thing on a project. It has not been renamed recently, but the problem seems to have started when migrating to Xcode 9.

Comment: @ChristopherGriffith not yet bro